# Redux Form 6.1.1 - validation on blur is not working on react-native

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-native

I'm working on react-native (Android) where I'm using redux-form 6.1.1.

One weird behaviour I've notice i.e redux-form doesn't perform validation  when I remove focus(blur) from input field, however on submit validation is working as intended.

Please guide me here. Below is my code.

**Text field component**

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType={ textType ? textType : 'default' }
  onChangeText={ (val) => onChange(val) }
  value={ value }
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  style={ styleInput }
  {...this.props}
/>

{/* Error message */}
<View>
  {
    touched && error ?
    <Text>{error}</Text>
    : null
  }
</View>
```

**Implementation of this Text field component as below**

```
<Field
  component={TextField}
  name="phoneNumber"
  placeholder="Mobile Number"
  styleInput={styles.inputs}
  styleInputWrap={styles.inputView}
/>
```

**validate function**

```
function validate(values) {
  const err = {};

  // common function for phone number validation
  validatePhoneNumber(err, 'phoneNumber', values.phoneNumber);

  return err;
}
```

**Note**: I observe that from ***touched && error*** condition error contains required error message but touched remains false even after switch/focus to another input field. As soon as I hit the submit button touched flag set to true.

Comment: Im having the same issue with react-dom. Your blur workaround did not work for me though

Comment: Would be helpful if you could share code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the workaround for this but still if their is any better way then please update.

below is my updated code(with working blur event).

**Updated Text field component**

```
const {
  input: { value, onChange, onBlur }
} = this.props;
... 
...
<TextInput
  keyboardType={ textType ? textType : 'default' }
  onChangeText={ val => onChange(val) }
  onBlur={ val => onBlur(val) } {/* <--- added onBlur function */}
  value={ value }
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  style={ styleInput }
  {...this.props}
/>

{/* Error message */}
<View>
  {
    touched && error ?
    <Text>{error}</Text>
    : null
  }
</View>
```

I just passed onBlur props/function provided by redux-form field to onBlur function of TextInput field(provided by react-native) and every thing is working properly.